# how to create a vector of Eigen::Ref

Tags: c++, vector, reference, eigen3

I want to reference discontinuous rows in a Eigen::MatrixXd. This will be passed as argument in a function, without changing the MatrixXd (row major) value.
Since I always need to select certain rows to pass into this function, 
I thought I could use a vector of References to the selected rows.

But even creating this vector seems impossible: points has `P.rows()` number of rows but every row is the same, namely the last row in P.

Can you tell me why this happens and how to fix it?

```
typedef Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::RowVector3d> OctreePoint;
typedef std::vector<OctreePoint> OctreePoints;

Eigen::MatrixXd P;
// load P from some file
OctreePoints points; 
for (int i = 0; i < P.rows(); ++i)
    {
            // OctreePoint p = P.row(i);
        points.push_back(P.row(i));
        // std::cout << p << std::endl;
     }
std::cout << points << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issues here: 
`P.row(i)` will have an inner stride, since `P` is (contrary to your assumption) column major. This makes each `Eigen::Ref` contain a temporary which holds a copy of the row (i.e., it is not an actual reference).

You have essentially two options here:

1. Use `Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::RowVector3d, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<> >` to get an actual reference.
2. Make `P` rowmajor by using `Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> P;`

Here is an example which uses (a non-const) variant of 1.:

```
    typedef Eigen::Ref<Eigen::RowVector3d, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<> > OctreePoint;
    typedef std::vector<OctreePoint> OctreePoints;

    // Alternatively, use this for P:
    // Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> P;
    Eigen::MatrixXd P;
    P.setRandom(3,3);
    std::cout << P << " @ " << P.data() << "\n\n";
    OctreePoints points;
    points.reserve(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < P.rows(); ++i)
    {
        points.push_back(P.row(i));
    }
    points[0][0] = 42.0; // Modify an element of `points` for testing purposes

    for(auto p : points ) std::cout << p << " @ " << p.data() << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n' << P << '\n';
```

This generates something like the following output:

> ```
>  0.680375   0.59688 -0.329554
> -0.211234  0.823295  0.536459
>  0.566198 -0.604897 -0.444451 @ 0x25b8c20
>
>        42   0.59688 -0.329554 @ 0x25b8c20
> -0.211234  0.823295  0.536459 @ 0x25b8c28
>  0.566198 -0.604897 -0.444451 @ 0x25b8c30
>
>        42   0.59688 -0.329554
> -0.211234  0.823295  0.536459
>  0.566198 -0.604897 -0.444451
> ```

Generally, I would be very cautious with storing non-copyable members into `std::vector` -- as long as you just `push_back` (or better `emplace_back`), everything should be fine. If you start moving elements inside the vector, compilation will either fail or may lead to strange results.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The provided solution solves the issuel. Not sure whether I understood though why the old element in points are *replaced* by the temporary element.